# Blender growing polygons

Tags: animation, objects, particles

I wanted to make an animation, on an modeled object, that it doesn't just appears like in the "build" modifier. Instead, the object should appear in small parts and grow fast. (So it builds together the model).

Is that possible ?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you need, but I can gude you to look for "animation nodes" addon. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nCghhlMOwRg

Comment: You could use a boolean modifier with an animated object to slowly reveal your model.

Comment: Is this what you mean? http://i.imgur.com/ckWAT24.gif

Comment: kinda. If you go into blender, scale the cube, use cell fracture and use the build modifier, i kinda want that but if you use the build modifier it just appears and it should slowly pop up and not just appear.

Answer (score 6):

There are many ways you could achieve "build" effect. The simplest one that mimic the Build Modifier, but does not simply "pop" the polygon faces are of course by using Add-Ons like Animation Nodes.

You could probably use Blender's own Particles as well to kind of reveal each polygon face slowly one by one?

One idea, using Animation Nodes Add-Ons:
1) Install Animation Nodes (AN) Add Ons.
2) Study a little bit a bout AN. Get a hang of it.
3) One of the Template provided to transform individual polygons will be perfect. The idea here is instead of appearing like a sudden pop, you want to use some kind of transition. The most obvious is probably to animate scaling of each polygon.
4) With a little adjustment you can get a more elegant "reveal" of your 3D model, perhaps in this case is basically polygon by polygon, as they are scaling from Scale zero to one.

[image]

Remember the way it is being revealed is also important and there are limitless way you could do this from basics to more sophisticated effects.

Here is basic:

[image]

Comment: pls tell me what the last modifier is called after Transform Polygon, i couldn't read it.

Comment: The last bit there, is the Polygon List slot that you get from New Generator Output.